# How the canvas manage the ratio of the image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

All:

I wonder if I draw a image on canvas, if the image ratio is not fit the canvas, how does canvas scale it( suppose only width and height set on canvas)?

For example:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="width:200px; height:200px;"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = d3.select("#myCanvas").node();
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function(){
        console.log(img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }

    img.src = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
</script>
```

The result seems that the image has been stretch a little bit vertically and squeeze horizontally, I want to know why canvas deal it in that way and how to draw it as it is or scale in its ratio like ?

I also tried giving width and height when draw the image, but it still seems not quite right, for example:

```
// in this way, the image still get stretched and squeeze
<script>
    var canvas = d3.select("#myCanvas").node();
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function(){
        console.log(img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth/5, img.naturalHeight/5);
    }

    img.src = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
</script>
```

OR

```
// Even I give it a 100 by 100 size, it can not do it that way
<script>
    var canvas = d3.select("#myCanvas").node();
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function(){
        console.log(img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }

    img.src = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitmap of the canvas is by default 300x150 independent of the CSS size.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="width:200px; height:200px;"></canvas>
```

This will stretch anything drawn to the 300x150 bitmap to fit 200x200 CSS size.

Use canvas' attributes (or properties from JavaScript) to set the size properly:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>
```

Comment: I tried this, one thing I am a little confused is: How the canvas deal with different formats of image, because when I tried the jpeg or png image to draw on canvas, it will stretch the image to fill whole area, but when I draw svg on canvas, it will just keep that svg image original size(100 by 100) and ratio and leave transparent blank space for rest of area. Does that means if the image is smaller than 300 by 150, it will just keep as it is and only stretch the larger image?

Comment: @Kuan the drawImage will override the aspect ratio if the width/height arguments are used. You can use transformations, f.ex. context.scale(0.2, 0.2) to scale it down proportionally (only using positions arguments of drawImage), or calculate the ratio manually. With the former you need to inverse scale the position though (1/scale x X/Y) The canvas size itself does not influence this as it is just the resulting bitmap, with the exception of the CSS size which can affect the (end result) ratio.

Comment: thanks, I wonder if you can help me with this code http://jsfiddle.net/kuanslove/adntrecL/    what I want to do is download a png same as the svg, right now, only half of the image been painted( even I have specified the width and height to 300).

Comment: @Kuan I believe you need to use viewbox combined with width and height (style will again only affect the element, not the bitmap, or view area in the case of SVG), See if this can help: http://webdesign.about.com/od/svg/a/svg-viewbox-attribute.htm. Result: http://jsfiddle.net/adntrecL/2/

Comment: thanks, I will study on that. BTW, could you show me the search procedure that why you think it is the reason of viewbox, I find it is really hard for me to find correct direction to search answer

Comment: @Kuan I just set the width and height attributes (removed the style). Consider open a new question if you run into more problems with the svg to png.